# How to parse sentences into tokens with either regex or toolkits

Tags: python, regex, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

How can I parse a sentence like this with either regex or toolkits like beautifulsoup, lxml:

```
input = """Yesterday<person>Peter Smith</person>drove to<location>New York</location>"""
```

into this:

```
Yesterday
<person>Peter Smith</person>
drove
to
<location>New York</location>
```

I cannot use `re.findall("<person>(.*?)</person>", input)` beacuse the tag varies.

Comment: You can use pipes (|) to find multipe patterns in a regex 
eg: (<person>(.*?)</person>|<location>(.)*</location>)

Comment: What about nested tags? What should be the output if you have them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look how easy it is using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """Yesterday<person>Peter Smith</person>drove to<location>New York</location>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for item in soup:
    print item
```

prints:

```
Yesterday
<person>Peter Smith</person>
drove to
<location>New York</location>
```

UPD (splitting non-tag items into spaces and print every part on a new line):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for item in soup:
    if not isinstance(item, Tag):
        for part in item.split():
            print part
    else:
        print item
```

prints:

```
Yesterday
<person>Peter Smith</person>
drove
to
<location>New York</location>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, how can I print each item on a new line:`drove \n to\n` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex -

```
>>> import re
>>> input = """Yesterday<person>Peter Smith</person>drove to<location>New York</location>"""
>>> print re.sub("<[^>]*?[^/]\s*>[^<]*?</.*?>",r"\n\g<0>\n",input)
Yesterday
<person>Peter Smith</person>
drove to
<location>New York</location>

>>>
```

Demo of the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/zM7lA5)